# Big-O Estimations | Getting the functions

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I'm having troubles understanding how to estimate the Big-O. We've had two lectures on this topic and the only thing I undestand is to take the leading coefficient from the largest polynomial in the function and replace it with an O so it would look like O(...)

During the first lecture this was shown

```
int i = length;
while (i>0) {
    i--;
    int j = i -1;
    while (j >= 0) {
        if (a[i] == a[j]) {
            return 1;
        }
        j--;
    }
}
return 0;
```

Followed by this on the following slide

```
int i = length;                 // Counts as 1
while (i>0) {                   // Counts as N+1
    i--;                        // Counts as N
    int j = i -1;               // Coutns as N
    while (j >= 0) {            // Counts as i+1
        if (a[i] == a[j]) {     // Counts as i
            return 1;
        }
        j--;                    // Counts as i
    }
}
return 0;                       // Counts as 1
```

From this, I'm wondering why

```
return 1;
```

isn't counted as a step.

Following that slide, it tells us that the

Outer Loop count is 3N+1
Inner Loop count is 3i+1 ; for all possible i from 0 to N-1

I understand that the second [while] loop will occur N times and following that, the [if] will occur i times where i is equal to N-1 since if j < 0, the second while loop will still be read but nothing else will happen after it.

The slide shows that the Total from the Inner loop is equal to
3N^2 - 1/2N

and that the Grand Total is equal to 3/2N^2 + 5/2N +3.

Wondering if anyone has time to walk me through how to acquire the functions used in Big-O estimations like in the example above; I have no idea how 3i+1 translated into 3N^2 - 1/2N as well has how the Grand Total is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain the calculation of the complexity of your example.

First we notice, that every operation requries only constant time, written as `O(1)`, which means, that the run time does not depend on the input.

```
int i = length;                 // O(1), executed only one time
while (i > 0) {                 // outer loop, condition needs O(1)
    i--;                        // O(1)
    int j = i - 1;              // O(1)
    while (j >= 0) {            // inner loop, condition needs O(1)
        if (a[i] == a[j]) {     // O(1)
            return 1;           // first return statement
        }
        j--;                    // O(1)
    }
}
return 0;                       // second return statement, executed only one time
```

The number of operations in every loop is constant, so we only have to count how often they are executed.

The outer loop runs from `i = n` to `i = 1`. For each `i` the inner loop is executed once and executes `i` constant time operations itself. In total we get

```
 3 + Σi=0,...,n-13 + 3i + 1 = 3 + 4n + 3/2⋅(n-1)⋅n = 3/2⋅n² + 5/2⋅n + 3
(1)           (2) (3)  (4)               (5)
```

Explanations:

1. The 3 contains the first line, the last line and the an additional execution of the outer loop condition. The condition evaluates `n` times to `true` and one time to `false`.
2. This `3` contains one evaluation of the condition of the outer loop and the first two lines in the outer loop.
3. The factor `3` in front of the `i` contains one evaluation of the inner loop condition, the evaluation of the if statement and the last line of the inner loop.
4. The `1` is for the additional evaluation where the inner loop condition evaluates to `false`.
5. The [sum of consecutive integers `1` to `n`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) evaluates to `1/2⋅n⋅(n+1)`. Notice the sum here is from `0` to `n-1`, so it evaluates to `1/2⋅(n-1)⋅n`.

The frist (inner) return statement is not counted, because if executed the algorithm terminates. But we want to calculate the maximum number of steps, the so called *worst case*. This case is when the algorithm terminates as late as possible.

Notice: The calculation of the steps is very precise. This is not necessary to get the big-O complexity. It would be enough to say, that each loop runs in O(n) and since they are nested the complexity has to be multiplied so you get `O(n)⋅O(n) = O(n²)`.